# Check if IdentifierUris exists in Microsoft Azure Active Directory Application using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am using following PowerShell script to create Azure Active Directory Application

```
$appName = "data-factory-app"
$appURI = "www.datafactoryapp.com"
$appExists = Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName
if (-not $appExists)
{
 if (-not $appExists.IdentifierUris
 New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName -IdentifierUris $appURI
}
else 
{
 Write-Output "Application Already Exists"
}
```

I am performing check for `Display Name`, I also need to perform check on `IdentifierUris` if it exists but cannot find any command. could anyone help

Comment: `$appExists.IdentifierUris` most likely

Comment: @Theo. i originally pasted code but editor was complaining of url so that's why pasted image instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I recommend using the [`Get-AzureADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/AzureAD/Get-AzureADApplication?view=azureadps-2.0) cmdlet from the AzureAD PowerShell module (the cmdlets are of the form *-AzureAD*), instead of the cmdlet from the Azure PowerShell 2.0 module (where the cmdlets are of the form *-AzAD*).

With this cmdlet, you can specify a filter as you would in the Azure AD Graph API [$filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#filter) parameter, and get what you're looking for in one request.

To get all Application objects with a given display name *or* at any identifier URI (technically it's a list) matching the one you've given, you can do the following:

```
$appName = "data-factory-app"
$appURI  = "www.datafactoryapp.com"
$filter  = "displayName eq '{0}' or identifierUris/any(u:u eq '{1}')" -f $appName, $appURI
$appExists = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter $filter

if (-not $appExists) {
     # No application exists with that display name or identifier URI
} else {
     # An application already exists with that display name or identifier URI!
}
```

Edit: If for some reason you *must* use the Azure PowerShell module (Az), then you will need to make two separate calls to check:

```
$appName = "data-factory-app"
$appURI  = "www.datafactoryapp.com"

$appExistsWithDisplayName = Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName
if (-not $appExistsWithDisplayName) {

    $appExistsWithIdentifierUri = Get-AzADApplication -IdentifierUri $appURI
    if (-not $appExistsWithIdentifierUri)) {
        # No application exists with that display name or identifier URI
    } else {
        # An application already exists with that identifier URI
    }
} else {
     # An application already exists with that display name
}
```

Comment: thanks for help. I use Az and not Azure and when i use this command Get-AzADApplication then your solution does not work. if i use Get-AzureADApplication then i receive Get-AzureADApplication : The term 'Get-AzureADApplication' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the answer, the cmdlets Get-AzureADApplication is from the AzureAD module, not the Az module. You can install it with `Install-Module AzureAD -Scope CurrentUser`. I've added an edit showing how to do the same this with the Az module, but it requires two requests, instead of just one.

Comment: in the rest of script i am creating resources; azure sql server, azure sql database, azure active directory app, azure data factory app, integration runtime gateway, ip firewall rules etc and I am using Az module for everything according to this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.0.0. If i install AzureAD module then do i need to change all my code to use commands from AzureAD or both can work in the same script.

Comment: To answer your question, you can use both the As and AzureAD modules in your script, that wouldn't be an issue. Glad to hear you got it working!

Comment: @3355307 I've made an edit to the example to show how you would optimize slightly by only checking by identifier URI if no match is found by display name. (This avoid an unnecessary call if a match is already found by display name.)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this myself, but this might help:

```
$appName   = "data-factory-app"
$appURI    = "www.datafactoryapp.com"
$appExists = Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName

if (-not $appExists) {
    Write-Output "Application '$appName' does not exist"
    # create it here?
    # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadapplication?view=azps-2.0.0
}
else {
    Write-Output "Application already exists, checking IdentifierUris"
    if (-not $appExists.IdentifierUris -or @($appExists.IdentifierUris) -notcontains $appURI ) {
        Write-Output "Updating Application IdentifierUris"
        $appExists | Update-AzADApplication -IdentifierUri $appURI
    }
}
```